# Break down a large folder into multiple subfolders by sequential names

Tags: shell-script

I have a folder with 20000 files in it. I need to split it into subfolders with increasing directory name (dir_1, dir_2....) with each folder having 500 files each in such a way that for example if files are from file_1.png to file_20000, the first folder should contain first 500 files i.e., file_1 to file 500 and immediate folder should contain files in a continued manner i.e, file_501 to file_1000 and so on. 
[image]

Comment: please _please_ do not post images of text.  Or, if you must, at least don't post such sparse images, and make them more helpful in the context of the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh

files_per_dir=500

set -- file_*

printf 'There are %d files\n' "$#"
printf 'Putting %d files in each new directory\n' "$files_per_dir"

N=0 # directory counter
n=0 # file counter

for filename do

    if [ "$(( n % files_per_dir ))" -eq 0 ]; then
        N=$(( N + 1 ))
        dir="dir_$N"
        printf 'Creating directory %s\n' "$dir"
        # mkdir "$dir"
    fi

    n=$(( n + 1 ))

    printf 'Moving %s to %s\n' "$filename" "$dir"
    # mv -i -- "$filename" "$dir"

done
```

The above would put 500 files into each directory (the actual commands that changes things have been commented out for safety).  The filenames are assumed to match `file_*` and each new directory will be called `dir_N` where `N` is a positive integer.

If you want to move the files based on their numerical names (the above sorts the files in lexicographical order), then use

```
printf 'Moving %s to %s\n' "file_$n" "$dir"
# mv -i -- "file_$n" "$dir"
```

instead (i.e. replace the corresponding two lines in the first script with these, in this order).

---

Shortened version:

```
#!/bin/sh

files_per_dir=500

set -- file_*

n=0

for filename do
    n=$(( n + 1 ))

    N=$(( (n/files_per_dir) + 1 ))
    [ ! -d "dir_$N" ] && mkdir "dir_$N"

    # mv -i -- "$filename" "dir_$N"
    # or...
    # mv -i -- "file_$n" "dir_$N"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd lotsafiles
for i in {1..20000}; do
  dirnum="$(((i/500)+1))"
  mkdir -p "dir_${dirnum}" # using -p allows this to be less noisy on repeat runs
  mv "file${i}.png" "dir_${dirnum}"/
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Something simple along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash
typeset -i i
typeset -i j
typeset -i k

i=0
j=0
k=0
mkdir dir_$j
for file in * ; do
   i=$i+1
   k=$k+1
   if [ $i = 500 ] ; then
       j=$j+1
       i=0
       mkdir  dir_$j
   fi
   mv "$file" dir_$j/file_$k
done
```

Not tested, so you might put an `echo` in front of the `mv "$file" dir_$j`  to see if it does what you want. Anyway it will give you an idea of how to do what you want.

Comment: Yes it works. That's why the `typeset -i` is there. Yes, I use string comparison, but that also works. Would you prefer I put `#!/bin/sh` as first line?

Comment: Using the string comparison operator for `test` (`=`) for numerical comparisons is bad practice.  Use the numerical comparisons (`-eq`) when performing numerical equality tests.  Using the wildard (`for file in *`) may catch more files than the specified `file_{1..20000}.png`.